# Testing Jetpack Compose - SwipeRight() For Back Navigation

Tags: automated-tests, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, swipe-gesture

I'm doing UI testing for a Jetpack Compose app. My question is, can you navigate on the previous screen using the SwipeRight() gesture? I've already tried it but it hasn't allowed me yet, I don't know if it's possible or if it only applies this gesture (in testing) to simulate animations on individual elements.

If possible, how it should be applied.

Thank you.

I tried using this gesture over the text of an element on the screen hoping it would help to Navigate back